# bluebird - fs.readdir().then - cannot read propery then of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluebird

I am trying to promisify the [fs readdir](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback) function using [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promisification.html). I just want to read all the files in a directory, and then output the array with `console.log`.

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'));

fs.readdir('./XML').then(function(err, directories) {
  console.log(directories);
});
```

I get the following output:

> fs.readdir('./XML').then(function(err, directories) {
>                      ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
>       at Object. (/Users/shooshte/Sportradar/notThatKindOfPeon/bluebird.js:4:20)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
>       at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
>       at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
>       at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
>       at bootstrap_node.js:509:3

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fs.readdirAsync('./XML').then()
```

[Documentation, second sentence](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html):

> The promisified method name will be the original method name suffixed with suffix (default is "Async").

Answer (score 4):

Seems like the library add "Async" to the method name:
It works for me like that:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'));

fs.readdirAsync('./XML').then(function(directories) {
  console.log(directories);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to promisify only the function you're going to use:

```
const readdir = require('bluebird').promisify(require('fs').readdir);

return readdir(dir).then(function(err, files) {
  console.log('FILES', files)
  return files;
});
```