# Return value of function promise.all.then undefined

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I'm starting to work with raw promises and async/await in Node.js.

I have 2 "promis-ified" functions that I want to run in parallel, and `then()` perform some manipulation on the result and return the new data. The return value is always `undefined`, but inside the `.then()` the value is what I expect.

This is my function:

```
const fs = require('fs-promise-util').default;
/**
 * compares 2 directories to find hooks of the same name
 *
 * @return {Array} hooks that exist in remote and local directories
 */
function remoteVSlocal () {
    try {
        Promise.all([
                fs.readdir(REMOTE_HOOKS_PATH),
                fs.readdir(LOCAL_HOOKS_PATH)
        ]).then(function ([REMOTE_HOOKS, LOCAL_HOOKS]) {

            //filter out values that exist in both arrays
            //this returns a new array with the values I expect
            return LOCAL_HOOKS.filter(function (name) {
                return REMOTE_HOOKS.includes(name);
            });
        });
    } catch (err) {
        return err;
    }
}
```

When I call the function it returns `undefined`:

`console.log(remoteVSlocal());`

I expect a call to `remoteVSlocal()` to return the new array created by `Array.filter()`.

Comment: `remoteVSlocal` is still an async call - you can't use the results immediately after callinmg.

Comment: Sorry I posted the wrong code, I'm not returning promise.all, I just want to return the values here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `remoteVSlocal()` doesn't actually return anything which is why the return value is `undefined`.  You need to return the promise and use that returned promise when you call the function.  Returning a value from an embedded `.then()` handler doesn't return from the function itself.

Here's a working version of your code assuming that `fs.readdir()` does actually return a promise (which btw is a horrible practice to take an existing standard API and change it's functionality - there are much better ways to promisify whole libraries).

Anyway, here's code that would work for you:

```
function remoteVSlocal () {
    return Promise.all([
            fs.readdir(REMOTE_HOOKS_PATH),
            fs.readdir(LOCAL_HOOKS_PATH)
    ]).then(function ([REMOTE_HOOKS, LOCAL_HOOKS]) {

        //filter out values that exist in both arrays
        //this returns a new array with the values I expect
        return LOCAL_HOOKS.filter(function (name) {
            return REMOTE_HOOKS.includes(name);
        });
    });
}
```

In addition, you need to return the promise from `remoteVSlocal()` and then use the returned promise:

```
remoteVSLocal().then(result => {
   // use result here
}).catch(err => {
   // process error here
});
```

**Summary of changes:**

1. Return the promise from `remoteVSlocal()`
2. When calling `remoteVSlocal()` use the returned promise with `.then()` and `.catch()`.
3. Remove `try/catch` since there are no synchronous exceptions here.  Promises will propagate errors via a rejected promise.

Comment: Right, I didn't include it here but I'm using functions that wrap `fs.readdir` in promises.

Comment: @AustinMeyers - I don't know what that means.  Your question shows `fs.readdir()` which does not return a promise.  In addition, you need to return the promise from `remoteVSlocal()` and then use that returned promise when you call the function.

Comment: I'm using a library to make `fs.readdir` a promise, this is at the top of my file:
`const fs = require('fs-promise-util')`

Comment: @AustinMeyers -  Well, then you also need to fix the other things I show in my answer like returning the promise from `Promise.all()` and using it.  FYI, it's pretty bad form to rewrite an existing API to work differently (and then not tell anyone about that).  There are much, much better ways to promisify a library (like the way Bluebird does it).  I consider that horrible code to work on or maintain and just downright misleading to anyone who reads it.

Comment: @AustinMeyers - OK, I rewrote my answer assuming that `fs.readdir()` returns a promise.  Still think that's yuck.

Comment: Thanks, thats totally correct,. I was hoping to avoid returning another promise but its clear to me now that `promise.all` returns a promise that I still have to wait for.

Comment: @AustinMeyers - Yeah once anything is async, all callers have to deal with an async result.  There is no way in Javascript to change that.

Comment: @AustinMeyers To _promisify_ the `fs library` in a _correct way_, you can do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40681657/2954267)